# disper -l on 18.04 generates a segmentation fault. Are there alternatives?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I've used `disper -l` for many generations of ubuntu in order to determine which monitor I'm attached to, and whether an external monitor with either vga or hdmi is attached.    Having now upgraded to 18.04, I find that this command is generating a segmentation fault.    The problem seems to be around for a while, as reported in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/disper/+bug/1655275?comments=all) but nobody seems to be doing anything about it.   Is there another program that has the same functionality?   I've looked at `xdpyinfo` which has a lot of information, but not what I need, which is enough resolution information to distinguish between monitors, plus information about whether multiple monitors are attached, and by what connection.

Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this bug, seems to be caused by some anti-Meltdown or anti-Spectre fixes or something similar (my [apport crash](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/375876360/_usr_bin_disper.1000.crash) contains strange line - `SegvReason: reading unknown VMA`). I have never used `disper`. Can `xrand` become alternative?

Comment: it does look like `xrandr` contains enough information for me to do what I want.    Thanks very much indeed for the suggestion.      Can you convert to an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I can also confirm that bug and it's totally annoying that disper doesn't work anymore. xrandr is not so "smart" as disper when switching monitors.

Comment: However there seems to be a patch: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844505 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=2;bug=844505;filename=disper_0.3.1-2.1.diff;msg=15 Is there a patched version available for ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Debian bug report on https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844505 was "fixed" by just removing disper from Debian archive because ( https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=946182 ): unmaintained, broken, dead upstream, depends on Python 2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this [bug 1655275](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/disper/+bug/1655275?comments=all), it seems to be caused by some anti-Meltdown or anti-Spectre fixes (or something similar as [CVE-2017-1000364 with Scilab](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scilab/+bug/1699892)) since my apport [crash log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/375876360/_usr_bin_disper.1000.crash) in [comment #9](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/disper/+bug/1655275/comments/9) contains strange lines:

```
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0x7f1233f14add <XQueryExtension+45>: mov    0x968(%rdi),%rax
 PC (0x7f1233f14add) ok
 source "0x968(%rdi)" (0xffffffffd63a1188) not located in a known VMA region (needed readable region)!
 destination "%rax" ok
SegvReason: reading unknown VMA
```

I have never used `disper`, but I can recommend `xrandr` as alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm the bug, too.

But good news! This seems extraordinarily **easy to fix**.

I generated a patched version (available on Github if interested),

```bsh
git clone <URL>
cd disper
make all
sudo make install
```

But please don't unconditionally trust *random sources* (e.g. me).

Read below for a complete guide on how to do this for yourself, instead!

## Cherry picking AUR into debian upstream

### Cloning and adding remote

Clone the Debian source (source [here](https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/disper)),

```bsh
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/disper.git
cd disper
```

Add [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/disper/) [upstream](https://github.com/apeyser/disper) as remote,

```bsh
git remote add AUR https://github.com/apeyser/disper
git fetch --all
```

```bsh
git remote -v
```

**[output]**

```
AUR https://github.com/apeyser/disper (fetch)
AUR https://github.com/apeyser/disper (push)
origin  https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/disper.git (fetch)
origin  https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/disper.git (push)
```

Yes, they're *different repositories* -- not merely different branches -- but for this cherry-picking patch it's surprisingly *convenient* to just pretend, for a while.

Just **don't merge** the "branches" unless you have a good reason, lest you cause an unecessary mess.

### Checking out the `master`'s

"Rename" (create new branches) their respective `master` (for your own record),

```bsh
git checkout -b AUR-master AUR/master
git checkout -b debian-master debian/master
```

**[output]**

```
Branch 'AUR-master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'AUR'.
Switched to a new branch 'AUR-master'
Switched to a new branch 'debian-master'
```

Sanity check on that,

```bsh
git branch -vv
```

**[output]**

```
  AUR-master    4c36710 [AUR/master] Update README
* debian-master e3ca840 d/control: Remove ancient X-Python-Version field
  debian/master e3ca840 [origin/debian/master] d/control: Remove ancient X-Python-Version field
```

**Seems good**!

You can explore and view the differences like so,

```bsh
git log --graph --decorate --oneline debian-master
git log --graph --decorate --oneline AUR-master
git diff debian-master AUR-master
```

### Identifying new commits

What we're interested in is that this,

```bsh
git log debian-master -1
```

**[output]**

```
commit e3ca840a48208a79a5c96da1bd9f6f1b845f5773 (HEAD -> debian-master, origin/debian/master, origin/HEAD, debian/master)
Author: Ondřej Nový <onovy@debian.org>
Date:   Mon May 14 08:10:02 2018 +0200

    d/control: Remove ancient X-Python-Version field
```

does **not include** the recent patch here,

```bsh
git log AUR-master -4
```

**[output]**

```
commit 4c367108b370d57ce178863fed7640bb846d3186 (AUR/master, AUR-master)
Author: Alexander Peyser <apeyser@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 23 17:16:42 2018 +0200

    Update README

commit 4c635d65244bcb2a86a9da86d00007de96a23626 (tag: disper-0.3.1.1)
Author: Alexander Peyser <a.peyser@fz-juelich.de>
Date:   Thu Aug 23 16:02:23 2018 +0200

    apply XOpenDisplay return type patch

commit 01132563030b9230e8f007794c3269dd913c3052
Author: Alexander Peyser <a.peyser@fz-juelich.de>
Date:   Thu Aug 23 16:17:07 2018 +0200

    Update INSTALL and README

commit d0498b7892b36d183d09b3d905296ee7456ff24d (tag: disper-0.3.1)
Author: dev-disper@willem.engen.nl <>
Date:   Tue Apr 23 12:01:43 2013 +0200

    also update Debian version number
```

Three (3) new commits! The second one is the fixing patch.

### Cherry-picking (what we want)

Switch to `debian-master` and branch a local version (to not confuse the merge with the upstreams),

```bsh
git checkout debian-master
git checkout -b local
```

```bsh
git cherry-pick 0113256..4c36710
```

**[output]**

```
[local d05e2bd] apply XOpenDisplay return type patch
 Author: Alexander Peyser <a.peyser@fz-juelich.de>
 Date: Thu Aug 23 16:02:23 2018 +0200
 1 file changed, 12 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
error: could not apply 4c36710... Update README
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Of course we expected a merge conflict...

But did you really expect it to be *only* `README`? Let's fix it!

```bsh
git mergetool  # or, vimdiff README (or whatever)
diff -NaurbB README* --color
git cherry-pick --continue
rm README.orig
```

I merged in the nice new section of `README` and sanity checked, then continued with an unchanged commit message.

### Bump the version

Identify where the version is kept,

```bsh
rg 0.3.1  # or, grep -rn 0.3.1 (or whatever)
git blame debian/changelog
```

So you can add a dummy release section to `debian/changelog` (for your own record), or not.

```bsh
vim debian/changelog
git add debian/changelog
```

I copied `0.3.1-3` to a new `0.3.1-4` section and wrote a few words.

### Test it!

Does it work?

```bsh
make <Tab>
make all -n
make install -n
```

Seems good to me. Let's install,

```bsh
make all
sudo make install
~~

Confirm that it works,

~~~bash
disper -l
```

Let's commit and tag it (for future reference),

```bsh
git commit -v
git tag local/0.3.1-4 -a
```

I really recommend a tag or something and a version bump. Be nice to future you.

Happy hacking.

Comment: Hi @Yngman, tried the above, or at least what I thought it meant: (sorry, I can't format a stupid comment):   sudo git clone https://salsa.debian.org/python-team/applications/disper.git
cd disper
sudo make all
sudo make install     But I'm still getting the same segmentation fault.     suggestions?

Comment: Debug!

1. To `disper.py`, add `self.add_option('--debug', action='store_const', dest='debug', const=logging.DEBUG, help='be very verbose')`
2. To `src/xrandr/__init__.py`, add `import logging` and in `get_display(name)` function of patch, add `logger = logging.getLogger('%s.%s' % ('disper', __name__))`
3. Sprinkle some debugging! `logger.debug("returning xopendisplay(%r): %r", name, disp)`, where `disp = xopendisplay(name)` before returning `return disp`

Other tips are `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` and `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: Hi @Yngman, thanks for the quick response.     Got stuck on step 2), not knowing any python.    Would you be willing to communicate by email?    Mine is leosimon@berkeley.edu

Comment: Very detailed answer, nice effort, I appreciate. You could avoid conflict with just `git cherry-pick 4c635d65`. I would not call that "extraordinarily easy to fix", still. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Disper is no longer in Debian and will probably soon disappear of Ubuntu.

I wrote a very very simple remplacement and published it here: https://github.com/fidergo-stephane-gourichon/simplest_external_screen_config

Here's it's README:

> Very simple external display management for the window system that is called "X" or "X11".
>
> It does *not* handle the general case.
>
> Intended use case: plug a screen, to your machine's output.  Call this script, optionally with a word telling the intended use:
>
> - mirror to have both display cover (roughly) the same area of visualizable video memory
> - left, right, above or below, to cover a relatively positioned area outside of main display
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> simplest_external_screen_config
> simplest_external_screen_config mirror
> simplest_external_screen_config left
> simplest_external_screen_config right
> simplest_external_screen_config above
> simplest_external_screen_config below
> ```

I have put installation instructions for non-developers to the README.me there.

Comment: If you use a laptop, you can also instruct your graphical environment to call this script, e.g. with "right" as argument, when you press a key combination.